# Regex to validate range of numbers from -10 to 10 with step of .5

Tags: php, regex

I got stuck with *regex* that could validate a number from *-10* to *10* with step of *0.5*. I came up with the *regex* that validates all negative and positive decimal numbers:

```
/^\-?[1-9]\d{0,2}(\.\d*)?$/
```

But it's a bit far off the *expected result*, which should be:

```
10.5   // Invalid (Should NOT pass)
10     // Pass
9.5    // Pass
9.4    // Invalid (Should NOT pass)
9      // Pass
1      // Pass
0      // Invalid (Should NOT pass)
-1     // Pass
-5.5   // Pass
-5.3   // Invalid (Should NOT pass)
-9     // Pass
-10    // Pass
-10.5  // Invalid (Should NOT pass)
```

[Example online](http://regex101.com/r/eN2hY4/1)

Could anyone please help to figure this out?

Comment: Replace the last `\d*` with `5` and it should at least solve your "random passing decimals" problem. May I ask why `0` should be invalid?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I the numbers are tied to the model that logically can't have `0` :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
^-?(?:[1-9](?:\.5)?|10)$
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `-?` makes the minus optional
- The non-capture group `(?:[1-9](?:\.5)?|10)` matches...
- `[1-9](?:\.5)?` one digit from 1 to 9 and an optional `.5`
- OR `|` 10
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Comment: Thanks, Ilia! With these character ranges it's easy to get it wrong. :)

Comment: And what would be the code to validate for numbers between 20 and 150 in steps of 10? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try it with simple snippet

```
^-?(?:10|[1-9](?:\.[05])?)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/PleWQJJ7EYXFhGge)

Here's also an example with all numbers: http://regex101.com/r/aE8iH9/3

well... after updating this, it look very similar to the answer from zx81

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below regex to match the numbers ranges from `-10` to `10` with the step of `0.5`.

```
^-?(?:10|[1-9](?:\.5)|[1-9])$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/57)